# Nexus TCP communicatio isn't working when AP don't have Internet, 4g is Enabled

Tags: java, android, tcp, wifi, 4g

i am using Nexus which have 4G is enabled and Connected to an Access Point Which don't have internet. 
I want to do TCP communication with my laptop which connected to the Access Point. But I couldn't able to communicate. Because of 4G is enabled. if i disable the 4G it's working properly.

Can you anyone help to  solve this problem.

Comment: Please read other stackoverflow posts about this 'feature' as it has been reported many times.

Comment: is there any solution is there ? or can you share the link ? it will be more helpful for me .

Comment: This issue is solved